Excel VBA: Clear the Immediate window in code, allowing further Debug.Print Messages to be output
I have some code
   Sub Test2()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rCell As Range
   Dim i As Long
   Dim resultArray() As String
   Dim resultIndex As Long
   'ClearImmediateWindow
   'Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Visible = True
   'Debug.Print vbLf & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
   Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Close
   Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Visible = True
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' Adjust this to get the sheet you need
   resultIndex = 0 ' Initialize the result index
   For i = 1 To 12
   Set rCell = Cells(i, "C")
   If HasAnyBorder(rCell) Then
   ' Store the result in the array
   ReDim Preserve resultArray(resultIndex)
   resultArray(resultIndex) = "Cell C" & i & "   True"
   Else
   ReDim Preserve resultArray(resultIndex)
   resultArray(resultIndex) = "Cell C" & i & "   False"
   End If
   resultIndex = resultIndex + 1
   Next i
   ' Print the accumulated results to the Immediate Window
   For i = LBound(resultArray) To UBound(resultArray)
   Debug.Print resultArray(i)
   Next i
   End Sub
   Sub ClearImmediateWindow()
   ' Simulate pressing Ctrl+G (to activate the Immediate Window)
    Application.SendKeys "^g"
    ' Simulate pressing Ctrl+A (to select all content)
    Application.SendKeys "^a"
    ' Simulate pressing the Delete key (to clear the selected content)
    Application.SendKeys "{DEL}"
    Application.SendKeys "{f7}"    ' Go back to VBE Project Window
    End Sub
    Function HasAnyBorder(rngCell As Range) As Boolean
    HasAnyBorder = rngCell.Value <> "" Or _
    rngCell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlNone Or _
    rngCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Or _
    rngCell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle <> xlNone Or _
    rngCell.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle <> xlNone
    End Function


The problem is that each time I run this the Immediate Window clears then fills with the other debug.print items so fast it is impossible to read. And a timed approach to each message works to slow it down but after the final it still clears the window.
I'm hoping to

run the code so that it refreshes the Immediate Window.
run the code
outputs relevant debug messages
stop processing but leave the Immediate Window Debug messages intact until the code is re-run.

Debug.Print "" as first line of code as suggested by somebody else
Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Close or
Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Visible = True
To test the code put some borders Left, right, top bottom of various cells in Col "C" results should be something like:
Cell C1   True
Cell C2   True
Cell C3   True
Cell C4   False
Cell C5   False
Cell C6   False
Cell C7   False
Cell C8   False
Cell C9   False
Cell C10   False
Cell C11   False
Cell C12   False

cheers for your considerations: Stephen G6SGA

When I run your code the debug messages appear and stay there - the window is not cleared at all.
If you want to read the messages as they appear (why?) then put a breakpoint on the line that writes the message and just hit F5 to move on
It's not really clear what you are wanting to achieve (or why)

I see the output in the immediate window. It's very quick. Before I rerun any fixes I clear the immediate window, at the moment manually. I just thought I'd do it at the start of each run of code. The Immediate window should clear on each run of the code after the first run. Keeping the outputs after each run in the immediate window until next run of the code.    Sorry but I am not actually a life long programmer this is all a late in life hobby for me :)

An alternative solution is to log to a file instead of to the Immediate Window. The following will do this (if you are using a Windows device ... an assumption, I know, and apologies if you are not):
Sub LogToFile(text As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = FreeFile()
    Open Environ$("localappdata") & "\my_log.txt" For Append Access Write As #i
    Print #i, text
    Close #i
End Sub

The file will be called "my_log.txt" and will be in your "C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local" folder (where %username% is your actual username).
Use it like this (so replace Debug.Print with LogToFile):
LogToFile "Hello"
LogToFile "World"

If you want to automatically include a date/time-stamp for each line in the file, change Print #i, text to Print #i, Now & ": " & text.
... you then don't need to do anything with the Immediate window!

In response to your comment which states your problem slightly differently from your original post ... Your call to ClearImmediate was commented out - closing the window and reopening it just redisplays what was there. So put that call back in and tidy out the close/open lines.
On the 2nd run it appears that nothing is written to the debug window but what is actually happening is that the debug lines have been printed before the SendKeys have had a chance to clear the window! You want that process to finish completely before your code moves on. To do that add DoEvents into your ClearImmediate Sub.
I adjusted your code as follows
Sub Test2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim resultArray() As String
    Dim resultIndex As Long
    
    ClearImmediateWindow
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' Adjust this to get the sheet you need
    resultIndex = 0 ' Initialize the result index
    For i = 1 To 12
        Set rCell = Cells(i, "C")
        If HasAnyBorder(rCell) Then
            ' Store the result in the array
            ReDim Preserve resultArray(resultIndex)
            resultArray(resultIndex) = "Cell C" & i & "   True"
        Else
            ReDim Preserve resultArray(resultIndex)
            resultArray(resultIndex) = "Cell C" & i & "   False"
        End If
        resultIndex = resultIndex + 1
    Next i
    
    ' Print the accumulated results to the Immediate Window
    For i = LBound(resultArray) To UBound(resultArray)
        Debug.Print resultArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub
Sub ClearImmediateWindow()
    ' Simulate pressing Ctrl+G (to activate the Immediate Window)
     Application.SendKeys "^g"
     ' Simulate pressing Ctrl+A (to select all content)
     Application.SendKeys "^a"
     ' Simulate pressing the Delete key (to clear the selected content)
     Application.SendKeys "{DEL}"
     Application.SendKeys "{f7}"    ' Go back to VBE Project Window
     
     DoEvents
End Sub

Here is an explanation of why DoEvents works and things to watch out for VBA DoEvents and when to use it
Incidentally I worked out what was going on by stepping through the code line by line - see the Debug menu.
And finally, having said all of this, see the previous solution - logging to a file is often the better option (which is why I upvoted that solution)

Meant to say thanks to you CHill60
